# excel formula to return hour based on time range

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

How would I use the hour formula to return the hour falling between two time ranges? The starting range would be the 1st minute of the previous hour up to the 59th minute of the hour.

if `[hour-1]:01:00 up to [hour]:00:59 = return [hour]`

Example:
Input:
`00:01:00`
`01:00:59`
`01:01:00`
 `02:00:59`

Output:
`1`
`1`
`2`
`2`

I am really stuck in figuring this out, many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for all your effort @ashleedawg. Really appreciate it.

The idea is that if the time falls between the first minute of the previous hour up to the first minute of the current hour, then return the current hour. Essentially offset the result of hour() by one minute, something like that.

`2:59:59 am = 3`
`3:00:00 am = 3`
`3:00:58 am = 3`
`3:00:59 am = 3`
`3:01:00 am = 4`
`3:00:59 pm = 15`
`3:01:00 pm = 16`
`12:00:00mn = 24`
`12:00:59am = 24`
`12:01:00am = 1`

Comment: is that input in 2 separate cells?  or is `00:01:00 – 01:00:59` a single string?  With that example, `00:01:00 – 01:00:59`, that means 12:01:00am to 1:00:59 am, right? - but you want that to return `1` even though only 59 seconds of that peroid is in the "1:00" hour?  Is that supposed to be `00:00:00-12:59:59` for midnight to 1AM?  Also, why would you need the hour "in between"?  Why not just get the `=hour(____)` off the end time.  Part of my reasoning for that is, what happens if the range is greater than 1 hour?  `03:00:00 - 06:00:00` , what do you want returned in that case?

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg sorry for the confusion. The input data are on individual cells and the range will always be limited to 1 hour.

Comment: ...so for 12:01am (`00:01:00`)you want it to return 1, and for 1:00:59am ('01:00:59'), it should also return 1?  That's more than a 1 hour period.  You question mentions the "59th minute" but the times in your examples show "59 seconds"

Comment: yes that is right. I am really confused how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(HOUR(A1+TIME(0,59,0))=0,24,HOUR(A1+TIME(0,59,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. the logic was already in my head, I just couldn't come up with the exact formula. Many thanks!